# Why does -webkit-tap-highlight-color not work with a minor change to my button?

Tags: css, mobile-safari

**Note:**

1. I *happen* to be using Elm + Elm-UI to build a UI
2. this combo renders "buttons" as divs with under the hood.
3. this is most likely a Mobile Safari issue and has nothing to do with Elm, but as of this moment, this is the example I have.

**The Actual Issue:**

When I use `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` I get the appropriate result on "buttons" on Mobile Safari, but only for buttons that contain a single Element/Div. If I have a button whose contents is a row with more than 1 Element, then the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` styling no longer has an effect on that button.

https://ellie-app.com/5FQV4QcFPCZa1

Press + hold on the first button to see the highlight. This fails on the second button.

Note that this SSCCE only works on mobile Safari on hardware (the problem doesn't seem to exist in the Simulator).

Thanks in advance for any insights into `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`, Mobile Safari, etc.

Comment: I don't really see what this has to do with Elm, or elm-ui specifically. If you instead make the example in plain js, html and css you would likely scare away far fewer people as well.

Comment: @glennsl I don't suspect it has anything to do with Elm. I suspect it might have something to do with elm-ui rendering buttons as divs. Though this is not specific to elm-ui. My experience is that people here get cranky without an example, and this is what I have an example for at this time. So it's labeled as such.

Comment: It's my understanding that tags should describe the problem, not which technologies happen to be used to illustrate the problem. If understanding the example language is required to understand the problem, then I think a language tag is fine, but I don't think this is required, or even particularly helpful, in this case. On the contrary, I would think it actually "scares" away people who might know the answer, because they think they need to know Elm just to understand the problem, when they actually don't.